# select the partners, where the first order was online

Tags: sql, sql-server

I like to the select the partners, where the first order was online. Partners can have more orders - so they should not selected if e.g. the first order was offline and the second order was online. I tried it like this, but it´s not working: wheat´s wrong?

```
select partnernr from new_table Where orderdate = MIN(orderdate) and ordertype != 'online' group by partnernr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select partnernr from (
select partnernr, ordertype,
       row_number() over (partition by partnernr order by orderdate) [rn]
from new_table
) a where ordertype = 'online' and rn = 1
```

Comment: Was going to propose same solution. You were faster a bit :) +1

Comment: This is not working - where should he get the ordertype from?

Comment: but you are only selecting partnernr and rn from new_table in the inner select - > so there is no column named ordertype anymore

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner You are right... Try updated query :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a where. Try

```
  select partnernr from new_table 
  Where orderdate = MIN(orderdate) and ordertype != 'online' group by partnernr
```

Comment: Yes - i missed it (and corrected it already) but it´s not working anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT PartnerNr, MIN(OrderDate) AS MinDate, OrderType
FROM Mytable
GROUP BY PartnerNr, OrderType )

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Ordertype = 'online' -- You use !=, but I think you 
                                             -- want to select them.
```

Comment: seems pretty correct for me: but haven´t you forget sth?

Comment: SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Ordertype = 'online'  AND orderdate = minDate?

Comment: The CTE only contains the MinDates. No need to filter again.

Comment: Try it and get back to me with the results.